# Cmd script using If Exists with a file version

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, cmd

I have 3 different versions of a software with 3 different uninstall strings.
Is it possible I can use a .cmd script to recognise the 3 different .exe versions to differentiate them?

For example:

```
If exists "c:\Program Files\xxxxxxx\xxxxxx.exe" and version equals "6.xxx.xx" GOTO Uninstall V6
If exists "c:\Program Files\xxxxxxx\xxxxxx.exe" and version equals "7.xxx.xx" GOTO Uninstall V7
If exists "c:\Program Files\xxxxxxx\xxxxxx.exe" and version equals "8.xxx.xx" GOTO Uninstall V8
```

If not, then I will split the collections into the versions but thought maybe this would be easier if it was possible.

Comment: what would you do if more than one version is installed?

Comment: It often amazes me as to how much information people are unwilling to provide, when they want the help of others. It is clear from the fact that you mentioned uninstall strings, that you know the display names for the exe files, those uninstall strings, the publisher name, the display versions, and within reason the install locations. Can you please provide that information. It is not possible for anybody to identify you, your company, or any other 'private' data from the visible information you've provided to this site, if you include all of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
if exist "AppPath.exe" (
powershell "(Get-Item -path "AppPath.exe").VersionInfo.ProductVersion" | findstr /l "6.0.0.0" >nul & if not errorlevel 1 goto uninistall-v6
powershell "(Get-Item -path "AppPath.exe").VersionInfo.ProductVersion" | findstr /l "7.0.0.0" >nul & if not errorlevel 1 goto uninistall-v7
powershell "(Get-Item -path "AppPath.exe").VersionInfo.ProductVersion" | findstr /l "8.0.0.0" >nul & if not errorlevel 1 goto uninistall-v8
)
echo The program or version was not found
```